# How do I have nested find_all statements in BeautifulSoup (Python)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I started off by pulling the page with Selenium and I believe I passed the part of the page I needed to BeautifulSoup correctly using this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="version_table"]/tbody').get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Now I can parse using BeautifulSoup

```
query = soup.find_all("tr", class_=lambda x: x != "hidden*")
print (query)
```

My problem is that I need to dig deeper than just this one query.  For example, I would like to nest this one inside of the first (so the first needs to be true, and then this one):

```
query2 = soup.find_all("tr", id = "version_new_*")
print (query2)
```

Logically speaking, this is what I'm trying to do (but I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax):

```
query = soup.find_all(("tr", class_=lambda x: x != "hidden*") and ("tr", id = "version_new_*"))
print (query)
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Whats wrong with using xpath for that?

Comment: XPATH provides too much information.

For example, inside of the XPATH provided might be 6 rows, with half containing a class with the word hidden which I want to omit.  Inside other rest are 12 columns, and I'm looking for the second item in those columns.  I'm not entirely sure how do that with XPATH.

There might be an easier way to do this, but I am still very new and might just not know how.

Comment: Yes, its possible with xpath. Alternatively you can iterate over the results from query1 and check if query2 is True. Could you please share a link? Hard to give the correct answer without an example.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a public link. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned without any example it is hard to help or give a precise answer - However you could use a [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('tr[id^="version_new_"]:not(.hidden)')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr id="version_new_1" class="hidden"></tr>
<tr id="version_new_2"></tr>
<tr id="version_new_3" class="hidden"></tr>
<tr id="version_new_4"></tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('tr[id^="version_new_"]:not(.hidden)')
```

##### Output

Will be a `ResultSet` you could iterate to scrape what you need.

```
[<tr id="version_new_2"></tr>, <tr id="version_new_4"></tr>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function (along with regex) for every element to do some advanced conditioning

```py
import re

query = soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: 
        tag.name == 'tr' and
        'id' in tag.attrs and re.search('^version_new_*', str(tag.attrs['id'])) and
        'class' in tag.attrs and not re.search('^hidden*', str(tag.attrs['class']))
)
print(list(query))
```

For every element in the html, we are checking...

1. If the tag is a table row (tr)
2. If the tag has an id and if that id matches the pattern
3. If the tag has a class and if that class matches the pattern

Comment: This returned "TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last)".  And yes, I imported re.

Comment: Could you show the actual part of the error, traceback is just the general name of the error message in python

Comment: The whole thing is too long to post here, but it highlighted the query and provided that error.  Also, down at the bottom it also says "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: based on that, it seems like the regex was not being given a string. I edited it so it might work now

Comment: Changing it to print a list still returned the same error.

Comment: I added `str(...)` in the re.search

Comment: did the modification work?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding: `query = soup.find_all(...) and print (query)`

`find_all` is going to return an iterable type. Iterable types can be iterated.

```
for query in soup.find_all(...): 
    print(query)
```